# Edit page SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, master-page, content-editor-web-part

I need to edit a page in SharePoint Designer 2013.
When I open the page in edit mode, I can see the web parts but I can not edit them.
How can I do it? 
(I need to add a CSS link in the Content PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead)
Thanks,Nk

Comment: What do you want to edit in the page.The page design or Webparts in it?

Comment: just add a link to a CSS in the web part

Comment: You can not edit content of a webpart that way

Comment: so how can I do?

Comment: PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead is no webpart though.. Open the page in Advanced Edit mode and you should be able to edit

Comment: How can I enable Advance Mode editing?

Comment: @user3387889 yup as robert mentioned edit in Advanced mode . you can see that option in the ribbon.Then add css link in Page head.Either go to sitepages or which library the page is and right click the page and select edit in advanced mode or click page-> Edit file -> On ribbon Advanced Mode

Comment: I see the button in the ribbon, but it is grayed

Comment: @user3387889 what permission do you have? You should have atleast Edit pages permission(Manage Hierarchy )

Comment: I am in the Owners group and I have full control on the site

Comment: right click on page, edit in extended mode

Comment: @user3387889 can you update your solution as answer to the question. So that it will be useful for others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the page in Advanced Mode (from Sharepoint Designer). 
If the button "Advance Mode" is grayed, you need to enable 
 "Enable Detaching Pages from the Site Definition".
You can find this setting on the site in the section "SharePoint Designer Settings" (`http://site-name/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx`)

If this option is also disabled at site settings level, go to central admin, web application->General Settings->SharePoint Designer Settings and select the checkbox to enabled detaching.

Comment: I waster an hour on other solution found untile this one.